# Local React app pointing to hosted Django server CORS no 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header

Tags: python, reactjs, django, cors, django-cors-headers

I am running a local version of my react app on localhost:3000 and am trying to hit endpoints on a Django server hosted on heroku

Error encountered on each axios request: Access to XMLHttpRequest has been blocked by CORS policy: no 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present

Current settings.py for Django server:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS=['*']

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'corsheaders',
    'whitenoise.runserver_nostatic',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'accounts',
    'blog',
]
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',

    # Whitenoise
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',

    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    
    
    #'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',

    # Machina
    #'machina.apps.forum_permission.middleware.ForumPermissionMiddleware',
]

# CORS
CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = False
```

Since I am allowing all origins to make requests, it seems like this type of CORS issue should be disabled. I have tried removing all other middleware except CorsMiddleware and it it did not make a difference.

A bit stumped at this point because my configuration seems correct as per https://github.com/adamchainz/django-cors-headers

Here is an example api call from my react app that is causing the "no 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header"

```
function callCSRFApi(){
  return axios.request({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'http://example.com/csrf/',
  });
}
```

One thing to note is that I am hitting endpoints on the Django server even though it is not configured as a django_rest api.

I have also tried setting a custom middleware which should always define Access-Control-Allow-Origin, but still received that the header was missing:

```
class CorsMiddleware(object):
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        response = self.get_response(request)
        if (request.method == "OPTIONS"  and "HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD" in request.META):
            response = http.HttpResponse()
            response["Content-Length"] = "0"
            response["Access-Control-Max-Age"] = 86400
        response["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = "*"
        response["Access-Control-Allow-Methods"] = "DELETE, GET, OPTIONS, PATCH, POST, PUT"
        response["Access-Control-Allow-Headers"] = "accept, accept-encoding, authorization, content-type, dnt, origin, user-agent, x-csrftoken, x-requested-with"
        return response
```

My thoughts are that the problem could be because we don't have the Django server configured as a django_rest app, or that django has logic where it can't be accessed from localhost.

Note:

- I test in an incognito window after reading that others were having trouble with the cache
- Have tried reverting to an earlier version of django-cors-headers
- Have tried without CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = False
- GET requests worked while running both the django server and react application on different ports of localhost
- Python 3.7, Django 3.0.7, django-cors-headers 3.5.0, React 17.0.1, axios 0.21.0

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True` in Django settings and `{ withCredentials: true }` in the axios config.

Comment: `function callCSRFApi(){
  return axios.request({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'http://' + hostURL + '/csrf/', // TODO: Will need to change to Prod
    withCredentials: true,
  });
}`

Comment: I set CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True in settings.py as well but receiving the same output

Comment: Added a new answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've had some problems with axios and CSRF myself and i like to just use the native fetch-API. This code works with Django and corsheaders:

```
export async function authenticateUser() {
  const response = await fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'X-CSRFToken': Cookies.get('csrftoken')
    },
    credentials: 'include',
  });
  return response.json()
}
```

Comment: The error seems to be different: [Access to fetch at 'http://example.com/csrf/' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request]. But the request is still being blocked by CORS policy.

Comment: Did you also install js-cookie and include the 'X-CSRFToken'? You also need the 'csrftoken'-cookie in your application (by logging in to the admin page for example)

Comment: At this point I'm just making a get request so I don't think I need the csrf token (but correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: One thing to note is that making cross origin requests between localhost:3000 and localhost:8000 works but when I try and point localhost:3000 (local react app) to example.com (prod django app) I begin to get CORS errors.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a white list to your settings.py

## cors

CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
'http://localhost:3000',
]